# How to combine 2 streams which both originate from the same source

Tags: rxjs, rxjs7

I would like to split a single RxJs stream into two streams and perform two different async tasks and finally merge those 2 streams back into one. The best solution I have so far is:

```
import { fromEvent, debounceTime, merge } from 'rxjs';

// SOURCE stream
const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(share());

const stream$ = merge(
    clicks.pipe( // stream 1
        debounceTime(1000),
        map((x) => 'debounceA')
    ),
    clicks.pipe( // stream 2
        debounceTime(2000),
        map((x) => 'debounceB')
    )
);

stream$.subscribe((x) => console.log(x)); 

// OUTPUT:
//   debounceA (after 1 second)
//   debounceB (after 2 seconds)
```

Now, what I'm wondering about, is this the best solution as I have now `clicks.pipe` twice in my code. I've added `share` to make sure that code (not in this example) runs twice. But I was thinking, is it possible with RxJs to somehow swap the `clicks.pipe` and the `merge`, something like this:

```
...
const stream$ = clicks.pipe(
    merge(
      debounceTime(1000).pipe(map((x) => 'debounceA')),
      debounceTime(2000).pipe(map((x) => 'debounceB'))
   )
);
...
```

Although this doesn't work it somehow makes more sense I think. Is something like this possible or are there better RxJs ways to do what I showed here?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vakoot-kwylrj?devtoolsheight=50&file=index.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, what you do not like is the duplication of the logic within `clicks.pipe(...)` block.

If this is the case, I would use an higher level function like this

```
function streamFactory(cliks: Observable<any>, debTime: number, msg: string) {
    return clicks.pipe( // stream 1
        debounceTime(debTime),
        map((x) => msg)
    )
}

const stream$ = merge(
    streamFactory(clicks, 1000, 'debounceA'),
    streamFactory(clicks, 2000, 'debounceB'),
);
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vakoot-2fjuem?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your point, you want want to avoid multiple subscription to click Observable (`clicks.pipe`), and have a similar behavior (debounceA after 1 second - debounceB after 2 seconds)

If so, you can use [timer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) operator :

```
import { fromEvent, merge, tap, map, mergeMap, timer } from 'rxjs';

let start: number = Date.now();

const clicks$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('click');
    start = Date.now();
  }),
  mergeMap(() =>
    merge(
      timer(1000).pipe(map(() => 'debounceA')),
      timer(2000).pipe(map(() => 'debounceB'))
    )
  )
);

clicks$.subscribe((x) => console.log(`${Date.now() - start} - ${x}`));

// OUTPUT : 
// click
// 1004 - debounceA
// 2006 - debounceB
```

Here is a working example : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vakoot-y3qiuj?devtoolsheight=50&file=index.ts)

Comment: Yes, this was what I was trying to do, thnx. If you use `switchMap` it does the same as mine working example (a second click within a second cancels the previous stream). But now that I look at the answers, I think the one using a high level function is better readable and the way to go!